# Table ignores page margins despite tarbularx

Tags: tables

I am new to Latex so I assume the error is quick to fix. I have a nested table and pre-defined page margins. Adjustbox is not a solution as it changes the layout. Tabularx does not seem to work? (I have now not inlcuded it in the code)... Can anyone help me please?

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{p{28mm}l}
\raisebox{\baselineskip}{05|2016-03|2017} &
\begin{tabular}{l}% first nested table
\bf blablabla \\
blablabal \\
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla \\
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, don't add an image of your code but copy and paste it in your post, so that we copy and run it, thank you!

Comment: please don't show code as an image, make a small document that shows the problem and post it as code so people can see the problem and test answers. You mention `tabularx` in the title  but neither of the tabular that you show is a `tabularx` so that package is not involved. Your inner text is in a tabular `l` column so is always one-line, even if you put it in a `p` column which could potentially be multiple lines tex will not know how to hyphenate `blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla ` so it would be on one line as it can not split it.

Comment: to load `tabular` package is not sufficient ... you had to use it ... instead `\begin\begin{tabular}{p{28mm} l }... < table content>  ... \end{tabular}` you probably need something like `{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{28mm} X} ... < table content>  ... \end{tabularx}`.

Comment: Do you really expect LaTeX to know how to line-break "blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla"? It's not a word in any normal dictionary, is it? Moreover, is "blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla" actually what you're trying to typeset? If it's not, I suggest you not bring it up.

Comment: Also if you are new to latex where did you see `\bf`  documented? It's been a deprecated command, not defined by default, since 1994 so wouldn't normally expect to see it in new documents. If this is in a tutorial somewhere let us know and we'll try to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need complicated nested tables, a `tabularx` is sufficient.

In the second table of my example I also show that, as David said, TeX doesn't know how to hyphenate "blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla".

```
\documentclass{article} % I've used article class because yours is custom
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{28mm}X}
    \mbox{05\textbar2016-03\textbar2017} & \textbf{blablabla} \\ 
                           & blablabla \\
                           & some long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long text \\
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{1ex}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{28mm}X}
    \mbox{05\textbar2016-03\textbar2017} & \textbf{blablabla} \\
    & blablabla \\
    & blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies for the wrong format and the usage of words. Obviously this was just for demonstration purpose. Also, thank you very much CarLateX for your warm welcome and your help, very much appreciated. Now, it works perfectly fine!!

Comment: @laufegge You're welcome, thank you for accepting my answer. Of course, I've added the second example only to show that even if the code is correct, sometime there could be other snares :):):)